# Cannot parse Curl Response from Soap Service (Post petition)

Tags: php, json, xml, soap, php-curl

im trying to parse a curl response for this request:

```
  $soapUrl = "https://soap_example_url.com/log_in";


    // xml post structure

    $xml_post_string = '
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:debisys-soap-services">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:Login soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <version xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$version.'</version>
            <userName xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$userName.'</userName>
            <password xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$password.'</password>
            <languageOption xsi:type="xsd:string">'.$language.'</languageOption>
        </urn:Login>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
    ';


       $headers = array(
                    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    "Accept: text/xml",
                    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                    "Pragma: no-cache",
                    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
                ); //SOAPAction: your op URL

        $url = $soapUrl;

        // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        // converting
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        // converting
        $response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
        $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);
```

But when i try to parse "$response2" i get nothing:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response2);
$json = json_decode(json_encode($xml));
echo json_encode($xml, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Here's what i get:

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
>
> {}
>
> print_r: stdClass Object ( )

When i use `print_r ($response2);` function i get this in my browser:

```
<Login2Response><Version>01</Version><SiteID>xxxx</SiteID><ClerkId>xxxxx</ClerkId><ResponseCode>00</ResponseCode><ResponseMessage>user logged in</ResponseMessage></Login2Response>
```

And when i use "json_encode" i get this:

```
  "\n \n \n <LoginResponse><Version>01<\/Version><SiteID>xxxxx<\/SiteID><ClerkId>xxxxx<\/ClerkId><ResponseCode>00<\/ResponseCode><ResponseMessage>user logged in<\/ResponseMessage><\/LoginResponse><\/return>\n <\/ns1:Login2Response>\n <\/soapenv:Body>\n<\/soapenv:Envelope>\n"
```

So i tried copy/paste the xml from my browser to a variable like this:

```
$returned_xml = '<LoginResponse><Version>01</Version><SiteID>xxxxx</SiteID><ClerkId>xxxxx</ClerkId><ResponseCode>00</ResponseCode><ResponseMessage>user logged in</ResponseMessage></LoginResponse>';
```

And it works, but i need to use $response2 to make it dynamically, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm closer i did this:

```
   $response2 = preg_replace('/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/', '$1$2$3', $response2);
   $xml = simplexml_load_string($response2);
   $xml = var_dump($xml);
   echo '<br><br>';
   print_r($xml);
```

And now i'm getting this response:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) { ["soapenvBody"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { ["ns1Login2Response"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) { ["return"]=> string(194) "018821909123400USER LOGGED IN SUCCESSFULLY" } } }
```

How can i access to only the ["return"] response to parse it as json object?